# comparing two strings using perl regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

How to compare two unequal pattern and get the position
for the following:

pat 1 : `<start>\d+.\d+/\w+\_\w+<end>`
pat 2 : `<start>\d+.pe/rl/\w+vivek\w+<end>`

i want output as

`<starttag>\d+.<NOT>pe/rl</NOT>/\w+<NOT>vivek</NOT>\w+<endtag>`

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You want to compare the regular expressions with each other, not use the regular expressions? It looks like you're asking for the Levenshtein Distance between the REs. Look that up.

Comment: Why does `<start>` in the original patterns turn into `<starttag>` in the result?

Comment: consider both as a string just insert '<not></not>' tags if mismatched found....just like any compare tool highlights the difference...output required is "<start>\d+.<NOT>pe/rl</NOT>/\w+<NOT>vivek</NOT>\w+<end>"

Comment: So go find an algorithm for computing the difference of two strings. I'll bet google can help you, especially if you start at the Wikipedia entry for Levenshtein Distance.

Comment: original string : '<start>'     find pattern : '<[a-z]+>' replace pattern : '<[a-z]+vivek>' Final string : '<startvivek>'

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Sometimes it would be better to look in another direction for the solution.

Comment: get find and replace pattern from user and return string instead of regex pattern

Comment: @Barmar: distance is a completely different thing from difference, and not at all wanted here

Comment: You posted a question that you later deleted which had "perl is developed by <match>larry</match> wall" as one of it's strings.  Was just about to post a solution, but your question was gone.  Let me know if you want that solution.

Comment: @Kenosis yes please do the needful

Comment: Can you either undelete the question or post it again, so I can submit a solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the output to have everything that is in both patterns, plus, in NOT tags, anything that is just in the second pattern?  Your examples are slightly different than that (e.g. `starttag` instead of `start`, `<startvivek>` instead of `<start>vivek`).  But assuming I'm right:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Algorithm::Diff;

my $one = '<start>\d+.\d+/\w+\_\w+<end>';
my $two = '<start>\d+.pe/rl/\w+vivek\w+<end>';
my $diff = Algorithm::Diff->new( [ split //, $one ], [ split //, $two ] );
my $combined = '';
while ( $diff->Next() ) {
    if ( $diff->Same() ) {
        $combined .= join '', $diff->Same();
    }
    elsif ( $diff->Items(2) ) {
        $combined .= join '', '<NOT>', $diff->Items(2), '</NOT>';
    }
}
print "$combined\n";
```

This outputs:

```
<start>\d+.<NOT>pe</NOT>/<NOT>rl/</NOT>\w+<NOT>vivek</NOT>\w+<end>
```

since it chooses to consider the / in the first pattern to match the first / in the second pattern instead of the second /.